# Building packer causes permission denied error

Tags: go, packer

I am trying to build [packer](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer#developing-packer) and I am getting this error:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet: open /usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/vet: permission denied
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Is the installer trying to access my /usr folder? Should I run this under root? How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Go are you using? If you install `go vet` it should work.

Comment: go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64. I installed go using my os package manager (gentoo)

Comment: My GOPATH is set and I am able to install other packages. This particular package is trying to install in /usr which I can't do as a normal user.

Comment: So did you install go vet?

Comment: try running `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet` if that works `cd $GOPATH/github.com/mitchellh/packer` and run `go vet` if that works, you should be able to run `make` with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

`go vet` is special, in that it's a tool that needs to go in GOROOT. In most installations GOROOT is also user writable, but if you installed via a package manager it won't be.

To work around this, you can do this as root to avoid changing any permissions in your GOPATH:

```
GOPATH=/tmp/tmpGOPATH go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
rm -rf /tmp/tmpGOPATH
```

Since `vet` is a tool provided by the official distribution, not having it installed may be considered a bug in gentoo's `go` package. The official `go` binary distribution included the following tools:

```
addr2line
api
asm
cgo
compile
cover
dist
doc
fix
link
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
tour
trace
vet
yacc
```