# Why would `go get` start to fail in Travis CI build?

Tags: go, build, travis-ci

I opened a pull request on a repository that goes through a build cycle in Travis. The [job failing is here](https://travis-ci.org/intelsdi-x/snap/jobs/100709221). I cannot find a good reason why this job in particular continues to fail. I've restarted it multiple times to see if it was a temporary timeout. The core error is: `The command "go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet" failed and exited with 1 during .`

Full log is here: https://gist.github.com/mjbrender/79e0343625038bce440a

Has something changed with Golang's `vet` package that I don't see here? Or is this just a flaky process? If it is, is there a way of improving the build process?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403883/building-packer-causes-permission-denied-error/33423926#33423926

Comment: Actually, though related, that's not the problem. You're on an old version of Go -- use go1.5.

Comment: What happens if you run that command on it's own from bash? Might get a bit more detailed error info.

Comment: evanmcdonnal runs fine locally.

Comment: @mjb: you should be aware of *why* it worked for you locally, either you had an older checkout of "vet", or you were using go >= 1.5. The key in the logs are the lines like: `package go/types: unrecognized import path "go/types"` which were added in go1.5. I'm surprised it was rolled back, because the "x/tools" -> "go/*" package migration was announced, but it seems it was earlier than planned.

Comment: @JimB - it's due to a compatibility issue based on version of Go - the failure is only on the 1.4.2 build, not 1.5.1. I'm running the later version locally: `go version` = `go1.5.1 darwin/amd64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I wasn't alone in having `vet` cause a broken build: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/4149

And it traces back to a change in imports. The team behind the package rolled back the change that broke `go vet` for 1.4.2: https://github.com/golang/tools/commit/da91609d887c6b1e28ad4548c47f3ff39a471989

`go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet` works now since that update to package: https://travis-ci.org/intelsdi-x/snap/jobs/100709221